# Upgrade 2+ versions of PostgreSQL on Fedora

Tags: fedora, upgrade, postgresql

I have recently upgraded Fedora from 31 to 34 (31->33->34) using `dnf`. It mostly went smoothly, but I realised that PostgreSQL cannot access my data. Trying to run `pg_upgrade`, I got

```
Cannot upgrade because the database in /var/lib/pgsql/data is of
       version 11 but it should be 12
```

So, the upgrade works only by one version.

How to upgrade by two or more versions?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is as follows:

1. Install your old PostgreSQL server from PGDG repo.
2. Use it to dump all the data to a file.
3. Go back to the current server (from Fedora's repos).
4. Import your data from the dumped file.

This is all done as root.

Install PostgreSQL repo:

```
dnf install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/F-34-x86_64/pgdg-fedora-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

Remove Fedora's PostgreSQL (it collides with PGDG's ones) and install the old version from PGDG repo:

```
dnf remove postgresql postgresql-server
dnf install postgresql11 postgresql11-server
```

Copy old data to the current install's dir:

```
rsync -av /var/lib/pgsql/data/ /var/lib/pgsql/11/data/
```

Run the old server:

```
systemctl start postgresql-11.service
```

Dump all the data to a file:

```
su - postgres -c "pg_dumpall -p 5432 > /tmp/dump_file.sql"
```

Undo the above (stop the server, kill PGDG packages, reinstall Fedora's ones):

```
systemctl stop postgresql-11.service
dnf remove postgresql11 postgresql11-server postgresql11-libs postgresql13 postgresql13-server postgresql13-libs
dnf install postgresql postgresql-server pg_top postgresql-contrib
```

You might not need `pg_top` and/or `postgresql-contrib`. Also,

Update `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` if needed (maybe set `trust` method for local connections?).

Put the old data directory away and reinitialise the dir for the current PostgreSQL:

```
mv /var/lib/pgsql/data/ /var/lib/pgsql/data-old
mkdir /var/lib/pgsql/data
chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/data/
postgresql-setup initdb
```

Enable and start the current server (the one from Fedora's repos):

```
systemctl enable postgresql
systemctl start postgresql
```

Import the data:

```
su - postgres -c "pgsql -p 5432 < /tmp/dump_file.sql"
```

Edit 2023-12-11: It seems that new versions of Fedora have the command `psql` instead of <del>`pgsql`</del>.

When happy with the result, you may kill the data created in the process:

- `/var/lib/pgsql/11` - data directory of the old server installed from PGDG.
- `/var/lib/pgsql/data-old` - original data from before all this mess.

You might also want to remove PGDG repo if you don't normally use it:

```
dnf remove pgdg-fedora-repo
```

This likely has a less clumsy way, but it worked for me. Also, please note that this was reconstructed from `history` and might have minor errors, but the gist of it should be ok.

Comment: the pqsql binary doesn't exist on my system, it's called psql

Comment: Thank you. Same on mine now (Fedora 37). I guess they've changed it. The directory in `/var/lib/` is still called `pgsql`.